# How to count values in dataframe with two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm newbie in pandas and I have initial dataframe with some data. For example numbers from 0 to 999 in table MхN size.

```
# initial dataframe with random numbers
np.random.seed(123)
M = 100
N = 1000
raw_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([(np.random.choice([f'index_{i}' for i in range(1,5)]), 
                                 *[np.random.randint(1000) for i in range(M)]) for n in range(N)]),
columns=['index', *range(M)])
raw_df.set_index('index', inplace = True)
```

like this:

```
index   0   1   2   3   4   ... 95  96  97  98  99                                                                              
index_3 365 382 322 988 98  ... 980 824 305 780 530
index_2 513 51  940 885 745 ... 493 77  8   206 390
index_2 222 198 552 887 970 ... 791 731 695 290 293
index_2 855 853 665 401 186 ... 803 881 83  350 583
index_4 855 501 851 886 334 ... 771 735 233 219 247
```

And I want to count each value for specific index like this:

```
index   0   1   2   3   4   ... 995 996 997 998 999                                                                             
index_1 19  19  29  30  19  ... 21  16  19  24  31
index_2 26  29  32  18  18  ... 22  26  38  38  19
index_3 24  23  32  36  22  ... 23  17  23  24  22
index_4 41  21  24  28  26  ... 26  30  33  33  37
```

My code do it in 12 seconds. Is there a way to do it faster? Twice for example

```
# create new df
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_df.index.unique(), columns=['index']).set_index('index')
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

# create new columns
unique_values = set()
for column in raw_df.columns:
    unique_values.update(raw_df[column].unique())
df_rows = sorted(unique_values, key=lambda x: int(x))


# fill all dataframe by zeros
for row in df_rows:
    df.loc[:,str(row)] = 0

# fill new dataframe
for column in raw_df.columns:
    small_df = raw_df.groupby(by = ['index',column])[column].count().to_frame(name='count').reset_index()
    small_df.drop_duplicates()
    for index in small_df.index:
        name = small_df.at[index,'index']  # index_1
        raw_column = small_df.at[index, column]  # 6943 
        count = small_df.at[index,'count']  # 1
        df[raw_column][name] += count
```

Comment: Can you provide a determinate, reproducible example (ie not random) for input and output?

Comment: [pandas count values with two conditions](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+count+values+with+two+conditions+site:stackoverflow.com&sxsrf=ALeKk026SmxZhsmbAlw3put7dxgeGYJnIA:1597523913811&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQnJyriJ7rAhXWGTQIHVpcAPMQrQIoBHoECAcQBQ&biw=1920&bih=977)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.  I started with the data frame you created.

```
t = (raw_df
     .unstack()     # move column labels down to row labels
     .squeeze()     # convert from data frame to series
     .reset_index() # convert Index (row labels) to ordinary columns
     .rename(columns={0: 'x', 'level_0': 'val'})
     .pivot_table(index='x', columns='index', values='val', aggfunc='count')
    )
print(t)

index  index_1  index_2  index_3  index_4
x                                        
0           19       26       24       41
1           19       29       23       21
10          24       31       25       29
100         17       28       15       18
101         25       16       27       19
..         ...      ...      ...      ...
```

I just transposed your expected value, so it would fit the screen better.

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = raw_df.stack().groupby(level=[0]).value_counts().unstack(1, fill_value=0)
df1
```

Output:

```
         0  1   10  100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 11  110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 12  120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 13  130 131 132 133 ... 963 964 965 966 967 968 969 97  970 971 972 973 974 975 976 977 978 979 98  980 981 982 983 984 985 986 987 988 989 99  990 991 992 993 994 995 996 997 998 999
index                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
index_1 19  19  24  17  25  32  25  17  21  22  26  29  26  16  22  23  23  22  25  12  22  29  23  26  20  27  20  27  21  29  29  21  25  19  21  19  37  25  23  20  ... 18  23  24  31  31  19  27  29  21  25  24  27  27  33  22  26  26  17  24  27  23  24  21  20  24  31  20  22  24  28  23  21  23  25  22  21  16  19  24  31
index_2 26  29  31  28  16  24  15  18  19  29  24  20  18  18  29  21  20  27  20  27  22  22  27  16  27  17  25  24  18  28  23  32  23  38  25  21  22  27  24  19  ... 22  23  24  18  25  27  28  20  32  38  19  26  27  19  23  25  23  23  25  23  16  21  15  29  23  24  16  26  22  29  24  31  28  17  34  22  26  38  38  19
index_3 24  23  25  15  27  21  22  31  24  21  24  24  29  23  18  20  21  23  25  22  24  31  22  30  17  28  33  26  33  28  20  24  23  26  32  23  28  21  18  48  ... 22  26  23  26  27  15  25  29  29  25  34  21  38  24  18  19  22  30  25  21  23  23  29  38  29  20  26  26  19  30  29  23  25  21  25  23  17  23  24  22
index_4 41  21  29  18  19  16  30  26  28  17  22  18  33  30  33  22  30  25  26  36  25  28  25  23  20  28  35  36  31  28  17  31  30  32  31  20  28  15  28  21  ... 24  27  31  28  33  25  31  21  18  28  27  30  27  27  30  36  24  24  30  27  29  33  20  27  25  29  31  18  27  27  25  26  36  29  24  26  30  33  33  37
```

For Sorted Columns:

```
p = list(range(0,1000))
for i in range(0, len(p)): 
    p[i] = str(p[i]) 
list(p)

df1 = df1.reindex(columns=p)
df1
```

Result:

```
         0  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  ... 960 961 962 963 964 965 966 967 968 969 970 971 972 973 974 975 976 977 978 979 980 981 982 983 984 985 986 987 988 989 990 991 992 993 994 995 996 997 998 999
index                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
index_1 19  19  29  30  19  25  20  17  22  24  24  16  20  19  25  26  24  25  22  26  23  20  33  12  17  22  21  28  24  17  26  20  22  24  35  22  23  23  23  28  ... 27  23  25  18  23  24  31  31  19  27  21  25  24  27  27  33  22  26  26  17  27  23  24  21  20  24  31  20  22  24  23  21  23  25  22  21  16  19  24  31
index_2 26  29  32  18  18  22  24  22  22  24  31  18  27  21  21  25  26  32  23  21  31  22  29  31  18  39  21  19  30  29  17  23  24  26  22  26  26  27  28  22  ... 22  21  27  22  23  24  18  25  27  28  32  38  19  26  27  19  23  25  23  23  23  16  21  15  29  23  24  16  26  22  24  31  28  17  34  22  26  38  38  19
index_3 24  23  32  36  22  18  24  23  28  30  25  23  17  23  39  23  41  32  14  21  34  23  26  22  27  21  27  16  27  25  27  19  28  23  24  33  26  15  22  19  ... 26  41  22  22  26  23  26  27  15  25  29  25  34  21  38  24  18  19  22  30  21  23  23  29  38  29  20  26  26  19  29  23  25  21  25  23  17  23  24  22
index_4 41  21  24  28  26  33  28  29  31  19  29  30  20  20  34  36  29  34  27  29  27  22  25  33  25  23  29  28  27  26  29  31  27  30  28  13  29  16  30  31  ... 25  27  23  24  27  31  28  33  25  31  18  28  27  30  27  27  30  36  24  24  27  29  33  20  27  25  29  31  18  27  25  26  36  29  24  26  30  33  33  37
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Update faster :

```
def f(x):
    y=np.bincount(x.to_numpy(dtype='int').flatten())
    ii=np.nonzero(y)[0]
    return pd.Series(y, index=ii)
raw_df.groupby(level=0).apply(f)
```

Output:

```
         0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    ...  990  991  992  993  994  995  996  997  998  999
index                                                      ...                                                  
index_1   19   19   29   30   19   25   20   17   22   24  ...   23   21   23   25   22   21   16   19   24   31
index_2   26   29   32   18   18   22   24   22   22   24  ...   24   31   28   17   34   22   26   38   38   19
index_3   24   23   32   36   22   18   24   23   28   30  ...   29   23   25   21   25   23   17   23   24   22
index_4   41   21   24   28   26   33   28   29   31   19  ...   25   26   36   29   24   26   30   33   33   37

[4 rows x 1000 columns]
```

---

Try this:

```
raw_df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(dict(zip(*np.unique(x, return_counts=True)))))
```

Output:

```
          0   1  10  100  101  102  103  104  105  106  ...  990  991  992  993  994  995  996  997  998  999
index                                                   ...                                                  
index_1  19  19  24   17   25   32   25   17   21   22  ...   23   21   23   25   22   21   16   19   24   31
index_2  26  29  31   28   16   24   15   18   19   29  ...   24   31   28   17   34   22   26   38   38   19
index_3  24  23  25   15   27   21   22   31   24   21  ...   29   23   25   21   25   23   17   23   24   22
index_4  41  21  29   18   19   16   30   26   28   17  ...   25   26   36   29   24   26   30   33   33   37

[4 rows x 1000 columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution in my laptop takes ~43 seconds, this solves it in 0.16 s

```
    df = raw_df.groupby('index').apply(lambda x: x.values.flatten()).explode()
    df = df.groupby(['index', df]).size().unstack()
    df.columns = [int(i) for i in df.columns]
    df.sort_index(axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output

```
         0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    ...  991  992  993  994  995  996  997  998  999
index                                                 ...
index_1   19   19   29   30   19   25   20   17   22  ...   21   23   25   22   21   16   19   24   31
index_2   26   29   32   18   18   22   24   22   22  ...   31   28   17   34   22   26   38   38   19
index_3   24   23   32   36   22   18   24   23   28  ...   23   25   21   25   23   17   23   24   22
index_4   41   21   24   28   26   33   28   29   31  ...   26   36   29   24   26   30   33   33   37

[4 rows x 1000 columns]
```

---

Update

In the name of science and with the only goal of understanding all approaches proposed, here is the time test with one loop per option and `time.process_time()` as the benchmark.

```
scottboston2  0.08s
richiev       0.14s
atanucse      0.16s
scottboston   0.30s
jsmart        0.39s
razor1ty      36.69s
```

As you can see all answers are at least 100x faster by avoiding loops. In general terms all answers come to the same solution of reshaping `raw_df` and then aggregating by count/size.

ScottBoston's updated version does all the heavy work in numpy and just groups in pandas, taking the lead so far.